# How do you float elements in a list of strings that contains some integers and some strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

The homework problem requires me to download a csv and convert it into a list in order to clean it up.

The list has both integers and and strings, and I need to use some kind of try and except statement to float the numeric values and the except statement to ignore the values with a string and continue converting the numeric values.

The list is as follows
`raw_pd =['002', 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', '405', '60', '62', '63', '80', '80', '60']`
I've tried multiple for loops with try and except but none of them seem to get the desired result.

```
    for item in raw_pd:
        try: 
             float(item)
        except:
             pass
```

the result is unchanged

I also tried

```
for item in raw_pd:
    try:
        int(item)
    except:
        print("This isn't an integer")
```

I expected the values to look like: 
`[002, 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', 405, 60, 62, 63, 80, 80, 60]`
but when I look at the list again everything is still a float

Comment: `float(...)` creates a new float object. You need to assign it to a name if you want to keep it

Comment: @MadPhysicist that's clearly the answer as I just posted. Why do people around here always post comments that are the answer?

Comment: One the first stumbling blocks in learning to code is mutation. You're going to have to learn what will change the thing in place vs. what will create a new thing and you're going to have to (much like operator precedence) just memorize it for every programming language you learn. Sucks, but them's the breaks.

Comment: @audiodude I don't want to speak for anyone else but I'd bet it's because when high rep users actually answer questions everyone complains that they never get a chance to post any answers. In other words, we're being nice.

Comment: @audiodude, often experienced users that feel the solution is too simple to warrant a full answer and maybe isn't even a valid question, will post short answers as a comment, to indicate that the question might be taken down. Another reason to provide the essential answer is because they don't have the time or inclination to provide a full answer that actually explains the problem, but want to share what they think the problem is. Your answer isn't bad, but it may need some added explanation for someone who makes the mistake in the first place.

Comment: I noticed your variable name is raw_pd. Did you use `pandas`? Is it acceptable to use pandas instead of list for your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Reblochon Masque says, you can use `isdigit()` to test whether a string is digit or nor. The code you want is:

```py
raw_pd = ['002', 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', '405', '60', '62', '63', '80', '80', '60']
pd = [float(elt) if elt.isdigit() else elt for elt in raw_pd]

print(pd)
```

output:

```py
[2.0, 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', 405.0, 60.0, 62.0, 63.0, 80.0, 80.0, 60.0]
```

Comment: So I get why you have the else statement, it's used to keep in the  strings within the list. I don't understand  how saying else element for element in raw_pd retains the strings?

Comment: It is a normal statement. Means `val = float(elt)` if elt is digit, else `val = elt`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this directly inside a list comprehension by first checking if the elements are composed of digits:

```
raw_pd = ['002', 'Ivysaur', 'GrassPoison', '405', '60', '62', '63', '80', '80', '60']
[float(elt) for elt in raw_pd if elt.isdigit()]
```

#### output:

```
[2.0, 405.0, 60.0, 62.0, 63.0, 80.0, 80.0, 60.0]
```

Answer (score 0):

Casting to `int` or `float` doesn't change the value in your list, it operates on the input value and returns a new int or float.

```
x = '42'
int(x)
print(x)
'42'
```

```
y = '24'
y = int(y)
print(y)
24
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can as an alternative to the above answers use .isalpha() to check if the elements in the list contain only alphabetic characters and thereby find which ones are numeric, as when using .isnumeric() on a negative number you will get a False response.

Let me know if this helped! Cheers!